# How to insert data into a Hive(0.13.1) table?

Tags: mysql, hive, hiveql

I am using Hive version 0.13.1. While trying to insert data into an existing table getting an error while using the below query:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (order_num int, payment_type varchar(20), category varchar(20));
INSERT INTO TABLE table1 VALUES (151, 'cash', 'lunch');
```

ERROR :

> ParseException line 1:25 cannot recognize input near 'VALUES' '('
>   '151' in select clause

While searching, got everyone suggesting above query, but unfortunately it's not working for me. Is it due to different Hive version? 
I am getting this ambiguity due to link [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-InsertingvaluesintotablesfromSQL)
 Needs help to insert data to an existing table in Hive.

Comment: please close this question as there is already another question asked by you and it has many answers to choose from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An insert values statement isn't available in Hive until version .14, so you will need to change your syntax to do a insert select statement.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE table1 SELECT 151, 'cash', 'lunch';
```

If you want to insert multiple values then you can union selects

```
INSERT INTO TABLE table1 
    SELECT 151, 'cash', 'lunch'
    union all
    SELECT 152, 'money', 'dinner';
```

Comment: is there any way i can add values for multiple rows?

Comment: You can do union operation to insert multiple values

Comment: OP, open a new question for this, including s rellevant example

Comment: @Jared  how to insert if table is partitioned? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54936354/hive-cannot-insert-into-table-with-map-column

Comment: INSERT INTO TABLE table1 PARTITION (order_num) SELECT 'cash', 'lunch', 151;

Comment: Note that the partition column has to be the last one in the query.