# how to insert multiple rows of data into a hive(0.13.1) table?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am looking for an equivalent of bellow query for Hive version 0.13.1.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE table1 VALUES 
(151, 'cash', 'lunch'), 
(152, 'credit', 'lunch'), 
(153, 'cash', 'dinner');
```

from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43807372/how-to-insert-data-into-a-hive0-13-1-table?answertab=votes#tab-top) answer it is clear "INSERT.... VALUES" query available after version 0.14.
so what is equivalent of above query for given hive version?

Comment: @Jared - I've asked the OP to open a new question for multiple values insert.

Comment: BTW, any reason you are using a version almost 3 years old?

Comment: I have no clue regarding it. Better person will be someone in my management, who provides me this hive version, to answer it :) .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to insert multiple values then you can union selects

```
INSERT INTO TABLE table1 
    select 151, 'cash', 'lunch'
    union all
    select 152, 'credit', 'lunch'
    union all
    select 153, 'cash', 'dinner';
```

Answer (score 3):

When using the "stack" function, the first number represents the number of rows

```
INSERT INTO TABLE table1 
select stack
       (
           3
          ,151 ,'cash'   ,'lunch'
          ,152 ,'credit' ,'lunch'
          ,153 ,'cash'   ,'dinner'
       )
```

or

```
INSERT INTO TABLE table1 
select inline(array
       (
           struct (151 ,'cash'   ,'lunch')
          ,struct (152 ,'credit' ,'lunch')
          ,struct (153 ,'cash'   ,'dinner')
       ))
```

Comment: I don't have Hive 0.13 but `inline` was introduce on hive 0.10 so it should work. It does work on newer versions.

Comment: i am getting this error while running above command `FAILED: NullPointerException null`

Comment: Hi @Sanjay, please check the edited answer for an additional option (stack)