# Hive: Cannot insert into table with map column

Tags: java, hive, hiveql

here is my table

```
hive> desc test_tab;
OK
test_map    map<string,string>
test_date               string

# Partition Information
# col_name              data_type               comment

test_date               string
Time taken: 0.087 seconds, Fetched: 7 row(s)
```

and here is my insert statement

```
hive> insert into table test_tab
    > values ('2018-02-28', map("key","val"));
```

but i get

```
FAILED: ParseException line 2:0 cannot recognize input near 'values' '(' ''2018-02-28'' in select clause
```

I also tried

```
hive> insert into table test_tab partition (test_date = '2018-02-28')
    > select  map("key","val");
FAILED: NullPointerException null
```

what am i doing wrong?

Here is hive version info

`Hive 0.13.1-SNAPSHOT`

Answer (score 1):

You can load the data into the hive table in two ways 
* Using HDFS command: 
Your table structure should by MAP KEYS TERMINATED BY '=' (Any delimiter)

```
CREATE TABLE `test_sample`(
  `test_map` map<string,string>   
)
PARTITIONED BY (
  `test_date ` string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  MAP KEYS TERMINATED BY '='
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
```

*sample input.txt 

Feb=28*

```
hadoop fs -put input.txt HDFS_dest_Path
```

Once you uplload the file into the Hadoop fs, then load data into the table:

```
load data inpath <location of the hadoop table> into table test_sample partition(test_date='2019-02-28');
```

- Using Queries:

If similar data already present in the file system you can insert that into your table via hive Query.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE test_tab PARTITION(test_date= '2019-02-28')
select map from  test_sample;
```

NOTE: MAP KEYS TERMINATED BY '=' constraint not necessarily required for test_tab table.